# Insert arrow into image in OpenOffice Draw

Tags: images, openoffice

I've opened a PNG in OpenOffice Draw (v4.1.2) and inserted an arrow onto the image.

[image: Image with arrow inserted]

I then right-click the image and select `Save as Picture`, but the resulting image doesn't have an arrow inserted. Puzzled, I repeated the process and noticed the image could be selected and dragged completely "away" from the arrow as in the image below.

[image: Image dragged separate from the arrow]

That shows the problem...OpenOffice has kept the objects separate (the original image and the newly-created arrow). The arrow has not actually been inserted as expected. How do you insert an arrow directly so that it will change the original image when using the `Save as Picture` option?

The [OpenOffice help for arrows](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Draw_Guide/Lines_and_arrows) was not helpful, only showing how to add an arrow...as a separate object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenOffice Draw is not an image editing application. It doesn't save the final work "as a picture". Draw saves in its own format where the objects stay unique in the way you describe. That's a feature, not a bug.

If you want to get an image from your work in Draw use the export function:

> File > Export...

Select your file format and name the output.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. Figured this was probably the problem but was hoping there was a way to "merge" objects. I later found the `File > Export...` option but it creates an image of the entire document (not just the little imported image and arrow) which introduces a bit of distortion. Will look for another way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Interestingly you can right-click the arrow itself and select `Copy`. Then paste that into an image editing application! :o)